# Cumulative sum while value I'm summing is unchanged

Tags: stata

I have the following data structure

| Y | cum_sum |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |

I would like to have cum_sum change so that it calculates the cumulative sum while Y is unchanged, so that the data is:

| Y | cum_sum |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 2 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |

Not sure how to do it and I've tried searching but the phrasing I'm using leads me to different questions

Comment: See https://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=dm0029 for some terminology and technique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. For more info, type help dataex
clear
input byte(y cum_sum)
1 1
1 1
1 1
0 1
0 1
1 1
0 1
1 1
1 1
end

replace cum_sum = cum_sum + cum_sum[_n-1] if y == y[_n-1]
```